# HTML 2x2 table: I want the first row is not divided in two parts

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I have an HTML table 2x2.

In that table, I want the first row is not divided in two parts but only has one cell that occupies the full width of the table.

```
-------
|     |
-------
|  |  |
-------
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [colspan](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html) attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use the colspan table cell attribute like this.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th colspan="2"></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Shouldn't have the second `td` element in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td colspan = 2></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Invalid closing tags for `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i should use `<th>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `colspan` along with `<th>` for the header row

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```